# Can I use an Observable's value in Object.keys as a component to the path?

Tags: angular, typescript, dictionary, pipe, observable

I am building a frontend that allows a user to choose an item from a dropdown. This item is then pushed into an Observable via `this.service.selectedRootPath.next(this.model?.root.path);` in a `(modelChange)` event in the HTML.

I then need to take that value and have it go into

```
childrenOptions$: Observable<SelectOption[]> = this.selectedRootPathDescription.pipe(
    map(d => Object.keys(d.resources.<THIS SPACE HERE>.children)
        .map(key => {
            return {
                label: key ?? '',
                value: key ?? '',
            };
        })));
```

Is that something that is even possible? I'm not sure what to do because Angular is not my first, second, or third language.

EDIT:

```
childrenOptions$: Observable<SelectOption[]> = this.selectedRootPathDescription.pipe(
map(d => {
    const results = [];
    Object.entries(d.resources)
        .map(([resources, resourceValue]) => {
            Object.entries(resourceValue)
                .map(([props, value]) => {
                        if (props === 'children' && value != null) {
                            Object.entries(value).map(([prop, propValue]) => {
                                results.push({
                                    label: prop,
                                    value: prop
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    }
                );
        });
    return results;
}));
```

worked the way I expected it to. I dug a little deeper to handle nested objects and figured out how to get the data I needed from it. What a PITA though...sheesh.

Comment: `<THIS SPACE HERE>` - what value do you want to have there?

Comment: I've figured it out Tobias. I was hoping to use a value from an observable and enter it into the path in the object.keys in the "this space here" but I'll edit the OP so I can show my solution.